# How to exclude dirty tracker from binder for one component (text field) in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, crud

I have crud and its editor. Crud editor is a dialog includes textfield and checkbox. Whenever I change the content of textField, the crud editor dialog enables its save button in toolbar. I know if I change something it makes crud dirty and button enables but I don't want to make enable save button even if I change text field.

Maybe I can remove textField from binder but I wonder whether or not there is another option to avoid text field to make crud dirty even though it's value changed. How to disable components ability to not make crud dirty?
I have added my Binder below.

```
Binder<Account> binder = new Binder<>(Account.class);
    binder.forField(nameField).asRequired("This is mandatory").withValidator(this::validateForSameNameCarrier, "A carrier with the same name exists")
            .withValidator(this::validateForSameNameRoutingClass, "A routing class with the same name exists")
            .withValidator(this::validateForSameNameAccounts, "An account or custom carrier group with the same name exists").bind(Account::getName, Account::setName);
    binder.forField(disableField).bind(account -> !account.isActive(), (account, disable) -> account.setActive(!disable));

    MixedVerticalLayout layout = new MixedVerticalLayout();
    layout.getRoot(false).add(nameField, carrierDragDrop, disableField);
    return new BinderCrudEditor<>(binder, layout);
```

Comment: "I don't want to make enable save button even if I change text field." Why? If you want to just have "read only" form, then you should use Binder#setReadOnly(true), when all bound fields are put into read only state, and no edits can be done.

Comment: Actually, I have one textfield and other components such as dragAndDrop table and checkboxes . I want to enable save button only if I make changes on the dragAndDrop component that I code before.